# Android - Issue with .apk file

Tags: android, installation, apk

I do understand that a .apk file is created in the bin folder of an android project, when the project is run.

I have a question about this: is it possible that there would be any difference in the functionality of an app installed via eclipse (as in connecting the phone to the computer and uploading and installing the app on the phone) versus installing the app by downloading a .apk placed on a secure server?

The reason I ask this question is that I usually put up the .apk file on a secure server and the testing team downloads and installs the app for testing purposes. The testing team has started to report app crashes when accessing this app. However, I don't seem to be seeing the any such problems (even while replicating the same scenarios) with the app when I install it on the phone via a cable connected to the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be falling into a caching issue. Make sure you get the QA team a new filename of the apk on the server to ensure that they never get a cached apk when downloading it. Also maybe create a md5 sum of the apk locally and run md5 on the apk on the server after upload to ensure it is the same.

e.g. use

> md5 yourapk.apk > yourapk.md5

on your machine and the server..

Most likely you QA team has found issues that are specific to the device or Android platform version they test with. Try with your apk with the same hardware in your dev environment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That was helpful - could you possibly throw more light on how I would go about creating the md5 sums for the apk files?

Comment: Actually, I figured out how to do the md5 sum. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no difference , if the apk on the secure server is as latest as you have on your computer.

I would recommend you to clean your project before uploading the apk to the server.

Regarding the crashes, i guess there are some location based problems.

Also check if you are uploading the apk from your workspace. or some other older version which is located in different place that you are not using anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I will certainly clean my project before I send it over to the QA team.

Comment: Also, by location based problems, do you mean the network through which the app was downloaded?

Comment: no, like if your app contains some location based functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how that would possible. The Eclipse ADT plugin just calls the executables in the specified Android SDK location on your hard drive and the .apk gets generated only once when you use Eclipse to install the application to your plugged phone.

Unless you're packaging the two versions in a different way, that shouldn't be possible. My guess is that your testing team has just found bugs specific to the runtime environment (the phone). Maybe a different version of Android, conflicting custom ROM, etc.

Comment: This is very good information - thank you! I will try to determine if the version conflict is causing the app to crash.